# App is not killed/restarted when location permission is taken away while app running

Tags: android

(in reference to the new Android M runtime permissions system) Everywhere I look, it says that if a permission is taken away while the app is running, my app will be killed (or restarted). However, when I try this, my app is not killed/restarted, and when I got back to the app, it crashes because the permission is taken away.

the device I'm testing on is a nexus 5, running android 6.0.1
once i get my hands on a different device to test on, I will update.

note: I didnt include any code or error log becuase I want the focus to be on why my app is not getting killed by the system like everyone says, and not on why it's crashing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recall seeing anything about apps being killed in Android 6. Just all the dire warnings about apps crashing when the OS suddenly starts throwing exceptions that pre-M apps took for granted.

Just handle exceptions whenever you do something that requires a "dangerous" permission.

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html#perm-check

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#normal-dangerous